# Is it possible to use Thunderbird as the UI for Outlook 2013?

Tags: thunderbird, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm having trouble with Outlook 2013--the UX is borderline unusable and I can't "see" my mail. My company uses Exchange and will not enable POP or IMAP access, so that rules out most email clients. (However, Outlook Web Access is enabled, in case that is helpful information)

However, I was wondering if it's possible to configure Thunderbird to connect to my local instance of Outlook?  In other words, Outlook would be responsible for talking to the Exchange server and Thunderbird would talk to Outlook. This way my email, calendar, contacts, and tasks would all be available in Thunderbird.

Comment: If they forbid other protocols it is most likely they forbid unsecure things like Thunderbird to, so ask your administrator waht is allowed.

Comment: It's not forbidden. Anyways the question is whether outlook will function as a proxy for exchange.

Comment: You could do something very time consuming importing Outlook mails. Then reimport and send them  from outlook(automated permanent 2 way migration). But this would be a) very time consuming b) errorprone c) if you try it not really what you want.

Comment: Thunderbird could however talk directly to an exchange server. If they allow Thunderbird, then what is the problem directly connecting thunderbird to exchange (also some warning: Thunderbird have a lot of issues with email-attachments which are only partial downloaded and so on. Because of the additional support (and of the additional security risks by additional - not centralized patched software) most exch. admins dislike Thunderbird)